# Как посчитать интеграл методом трапеции и Симпсона на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Вычислить приближённо интеграл точностью до 0.01

- по формуле левых и правых прямоугольников, найдя число интервалов разбиения;
- по формуле трапеций, найдя число интервалов разбиения;
- по формуле Симпсона, найдя число интервалов разбиения;
- по формуле трапеций, с помощью метода двойного пересчета;
- по формуле Симпсона, с помощью метода двойного пересчета.

Методом прямоугольников посчитал, а вот с трапецией и Симпсоном не получается

```
from math import *
import numpy as np


def work(f, a, b, n):
   print("\nТекущее число разбиений: ", n)
   h = (b - a) / float(n)
   print("Текущий шаг:", h)
   total = sum([f((a + (k * h))) for k in range(0, n)])
   result = h * total
   print("Текущий результат: ", result)
   return result


# Туть подъинтегральная функция
def f(x):
    return (pow(x, 2)) * (pow(sin(x), 2))


print("Используем формулу левых прямоугольников")
print("Интегрируемая функция: f(x) = x^2*sin x^2")
print("Точность: 0.01")

n = 2
a1 = work(f, 1, 1.6, n)
n *= 2
a2 = work(f, 1, 1.6, n)

while abs(a1 - a2) > 0.01:
    n *= 2
    a1 = work(f, 1, 1.6, n)
    n *= 2
    a2 = work(f, 1, 1.6, n)

print("\nОтвет:", a2, "\nКоличество разбиений:", n)


def simpson(left, right, n, function):
   h = (right - left) / (2 * n)

   tmp_sum = function(left) + function(right)

   for step in range(1, 2 * n):
       if step % 2 != 0:
           tmp_sum += 4 * function(left + step * h)
       else:
           tmp_sum += 2 * function(left + step * h)

   return tmp_sum * h / 3


def trapezian(left, right, n, function):
    h = (right - left) / (n)

    return (function(left) + function(right) +
        sum(function(left + step * h) for step in range(1, n))) * h


print(simpson(0, 5, 15, f))
print(trapezian(0, 5, 30, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

В формуле Симпсона умножается в конце на h / 6, а не на h / 3